# Using OpenDayLight with NS-3 simulator

Tags: opendaylight, ns-3

I am an undergraduate student and I am currently tasked to simulate a network using the NS-3 simulator and OFSwitch 1.3 in conjunction with the OpenDayLight controller. Is there any way I could use the ODL controller like I would with the mininet simulator, and if yes, how?

Comment: Someone's studying in DI I think.

Comment: Yes I do. And so do you if I'm not mistaken